# Peewee, как искать значения в sqlite подобно %LIKE% в Mysql?

Tags: python, orm, search, peewee, python-3.7

Вопрос скорей всего глупый, но я не могу понять как реализовать поиск по нику, фамилии и id.

Модель:

```
aid = IntegerField()
firstname = CharField(null=True)
lastname = CharField(null=True)
nickname = CharField(null=True)
sex = IntegerField(null=True)
icon = CharField(null=True)
```

Нужно осуществить поиск сразу по nickname(если переменная содержит пробелы), aid (если переменная integer), lastname.

Comment: `WHERE field LIKE '%substring%'` эквивалентен `WHERE INSTR(field, 'substring') > 0`. И не исключено, что можно просто `WHERE INSTR(field, 'substring')`.

Comment: Поясните, с чем именно у вас проблема. Вы не знаете как делать выборки в Peewee? Как их ограничивать? Как использовать where like? Как искать по нескольким полям? Или вы всё это знаете и успешно применяется в MySQL, а с SQLite тот же код не работает?

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev , нужна именно выборка по трем значением. Я не знаю как правильно делать выборку на peewee.

Answer (score 0):

```
var = 'John Doe'
users = []
if isinstance(var, int):
    users = User.select().where(User.aid == var)
elif isinstance(var, int):
    users = User.select().where(User.nickname.contains(var) | User.lastname.contains(var))
else:
    raise ValueError('У пользователей нет полей этого типа')
```

Но обычно код проверяющий тип переменной - это признак плохо спроектированного приложения. По возможности избегайте этого.

Comment: это выборка, а нужен поиск, например в базе John, а юсер пишет Joh

Comment: `contains` именно так и работает.